# make vim recognize dollar sign as start of sentence

Tags: vim, latex

Suppose I have something written in latex like this:

```
\begin{problem}
    [37]
\end{problem}
\begin{solution}
  $A$ is not equal to $B$. $C$ is not equal to $D$. 
\end{solution}
```

If I have my cursor in the 2nd sentence, "das" will act as I expect it to. But if I have my cursor in the 1st sentence, "das" will delete everything before "$C$ is not equal to $D$.", including the first 4 lines ("\begin{problem} to \begin{solution}). How can I make vim not delete the first 4 lines? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that you can change this.  Vim is seeing `<whitespace>$A$ is not equal to $B$.<whitespace>` as the sentence.  If you use `dis` instead it will preserve the space between the sentences but I am assuming that you want it to preserve the space before the sentence.

I was curious, so I looked it up in the documentation for ["das"](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#das):

> "das"   delete a sentence           *das*

A sentence is defined as:

> A sentence is defined as ending at a '.', '!' or '?' followed by either the
>   end of a line, or by a space or tab.  Any number of closing ')', ']', '"''
>   and ''' characters may appear after the '.', '!' or '?' before the spaces,
>   tabs or end of line.  A paragraph and section boundary is also a sentence
>   boundary.
>
> If the 'J' flag is present in 'cpoptions', at least two spaces have to
>   follow the punctuation mark; s are not recognized as white space.
>   The definition of a sentence cannot be changed.

The last line is what is important: *The definition of a sentence cannot be changed.*  This is a bit surprising given the general flexibility of vim, but I guess that there are limits around if you look hard enough.

Comment: While the definition of sentence cannot be changed, you can create a bunch of mappings: `onoremap` `as` and `is`, `noremap` `<backtick>(`, `<backtick>)`, `'(`, `')`, `(` and `)`, `xnoremap` `as` and `is`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is just to add a newline after `\begin{solution}`.